# Проблема с изменением высоты балун панели

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Почему при balloonPanelMaxMapArea: Infinity можно задать минимальную высоту при помощи balloonMinHeight, к примеру:
 geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {.. }, {preset: mark, balloonMinHeight : 300} ));
А максимальную высоту балуна, при помощи  balloonMaxHeight : 80, не получается?
Возможно ли вообще задать максимальную высоту балуна 80 пикселей, с учетом того, чтобы балун раскрывался внизу карты?

Answer (score 1):

Можно задать

```
balloonPanelMaxHeightRatio: 0.1
```

Где 0.1 это максимальная высота по отношению к карте. То есть нужно высчитать высоту карты и задать нужную высоту. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/#Balloon__param-options

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло)